# How to make the Ajax call again in case Time out error occurs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a document ready function inside my html  file as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   cust_id = getParameterByName('customer_id');

    var locationAjaxCall = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url+'/OMS/oms1/getlocationscreen?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        }
    });
    locationAjaxCall.done(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
             timeout: 5000,
            success: function(response) {
            },
             error: function(x, t, m) {
            if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
            }
    }
});
}).done(function() {
    });
});
```

For the second Ajax call . i am keeping a **timeout** for 5 seconds as shown below

My question is  in case a timeout occurs during the second Ajax call , how can i make that Ajax call again ??

(I don't want to reload the entire page as i might lose some data which was already set )

Please let me know if its possible ??

Comment: You mean if after 5 secs it's not finished, re-fire it. So why do you have 5 sec limit to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? Using setInterval and clear the interval when its successful.

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
    {
       cust_id = getParameterByName('customer_id');

        var locationAjaxCall = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'/OMS/oms1/getlocationscreen?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            }
        });
        locationAjaxCall.done(function() {
            var intvl=setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: false,
                 timeout: 5000,
                success: function(response) {
                 clearInterval(intvl);
                },
                 error: function(x, t, m) {
                if(t==="timeout") {
                alert("got timeout");
                }
              }
          });
        },5000);
      }).done(function() {
     });
    });
```

Comment: setInterval keeps sending the request every 5 seconds and clearInterval stops it from sending it again once there is a response from the ajax call.

Comment: should i create a new function by name clearInterval() ?? and what should be the logic under it now ??

Comment: clearInterval() is an intrinsic function that clears the timer set by setInterval(). For more information, you can read here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp. Also, in your code I can't understand a few things you're trying to do. You're calling success: and .done(). Only one of them is necessary. Also, you're chaining the second done to the done of the first ajax call which seems redundant. Can you tell me what you're trying to do and I'll try to help?

Comment: I have used success and ajax because somecases the ajax responses are gettng mixed up . so i have coded that way .

Answer (score 1):

Move second AJAX call to some function, maybe? And when timeout occurs, call it again.

```
function fname() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(response) {
                // success
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
                if(t==="timeout") {
                    alert("got timeout");
                    fname();
                }
            }
    });
}
```